# discord.py not sending message when channel is created

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_channel_create(channel):
    if channel.name.startswith('ticket'):
        #send an embed in the channel
        await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(title='Ticket Created', description='Thank you for creating a ticket.', color=0x00ff00))
        print('[$] Ticket Created at ' + channel.name)
```

My code is supposed to send an embed and log when a ticket is made, but the bot doesn't recognize when channels are created (that start with "ticket").

Answer (score 1):

There is no `on_channel_create` event. You're looking for [`on_guild_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_channel_create).